# Marshalling a pointer of struct in C++ to an array in C#

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, struct, marshalling

I have the following C++ structs:

```
typedef struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
} Point;


typedef struct IMTResult
{
    int    numberOfPoints;
    Point* vect_intima;
    Point* vect_media;
    Point* vect_adventitia;
} IMTResult;
```

Where `numberOfPoints` is the length of each pointer of `Point`

And this C++ function:

```
bool setSecondPoint( int x, int y, IMTResult* result );
```

How can I marshall this IMTResult struct in C#?
I tried:

```
public struct IMTResult
{
    public int numberOfPoints;
    public IntPtr vect_intima;
    public IntPtr vect_media;
    public IntPtr vect_adventitia;
}
```

And tried to manage myself the three vectors using:

```
[DllImport("MyDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern bool setSecondPoint(int x, int y, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref IMTResult result);

public bool dllSetSecondPoint(int x, int y, ref IMTResult result)
{
    bool res = setSecondPoint(x, y, ref result);

    int structSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Point));
    Point vect = new Point();
    IntPtr ptr = result.vect_media;
    for (int i = 0; i < result.numberOfPoints; i++)
    {
        Point vect = (Point) Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(Point));
        ptr = (IntPtr)((int)ptr + structSize);
    }

    return res;
}
```

But `vect` always results in a vector where `x` and `y` are equal to -1
. I also tried to marshal as attribute each of these vectors unsuccessfully.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: Have you examined the pointers to see if they're reasonable?  If the pointer offset in the structure is wrong the data will be invalid... have you confirmed that the struct size of `IMTResult` is consistent between C# and C++?   Most of these issues are because of misalignment of the struct members, because of packing or type size differences.  32-bit or 64-bit pointers, packing, etc all play a part.

Answer (score -1):

In fact, there was no problem at all. The code is absolutely correct. Thanks!